# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser returns null on multiple classes

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse this HTML from remote url using Simple HTML DOM Parser:

```
<div class="_5pbx userContent _3ds9 _3576" data-ft="data-ft='{"tn":"K"}'">
<p>text to be parsed</p>
<p>the rest of text</p>
</div>
```

The PHP snipe I used is as the following:

```
include (getdomain . "/lib/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$get = file_get_contents("http://localhost/get/d.json");
$html->load($get);
foreach ($html->find('div[class=_5pbx userContent _3ds9 _3576]') as $link) {
 if(isset($link)){
          echo $link->plaintext ;
    }
  }
```

But it didn't work, I'm aware of the `<p>` tag and I tried to add if statement for that but still didn't work, as the following:

```
include (getdomain . "/lib/simple_html_dom.php");

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$get = file_get_contents("http://localhost/get/d.html");
$html->load($get);
foreach ($html->find('div[class=_5pbx userContent _3ds9 _3576]') as $link) {
 if(isset($link)){
foreach($link->find('p') as $tag)
    {
          echo $tag->plaintext ;
    }
  }
}
```

But all didn't work :(

Any idea?

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors or warnings either displayed or logged? Also, in your include, is the `getdomain` a defined symbol in your system? Or is it a function?

Comment: Yes getdomain to get the domain, I the code works when i try to get other elements like title `echo $html->find('title',0)->plaintext;`, but for the class with multiple classes it fails.

Comment: Firstly, think about what you're naming and why. If getdomain is a method, think also about `camelCase` and I'm pretty sure that a method or function always requires `()` if said method/function requires no additional parameters - if it's a defined constant then I would use `CAPSCASE`, not because you want to shout at other developers, but to alert them that `getdomain` is a constant. Otherwise it looks like a typo, either a variable with a missing `$` at the start, or a function/method with missing `()` - finally `getdomain` sounds like a `getter` so how would one set it?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this. It is working..

```
<?php
include (getcwd() . "/simple_html_dom.php");
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$get = file_get_contents("http://localhost/zdemo/php%20selenium/d.json");
$html->load($get);
foreach ($html->find('div[class=_5pbx userContent _3ds9 _3576]') as $link) 
{
    if(isset($link))
    {
          echo $link->plaintext ;
    }
}
```